# Reduce number of posts depending on post content

Tags: wordpress

In a custom post archive; Is it possible to reduce the the number of posts shown, depending on the contents of the showing posts?

I have a custom post type for products. In the product archive there are 20 products showing on each page, 4 rows, 5 cols.
In some cases where the product image is super wide I'd like that product to be shown with double width.

When showing a super wide product, I'd like to reduce the number of posts to 19 (18 if there are two super wide products). Keeping the bottom line straight.

---

This is the loop for my custom post archive.
I got your point with numcols. And as you say, I should probably modify the query, making sure that page 2 and 3 (and on) shows the right posts.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="produkt_item normal various" data-fancybox-type="iframe">
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
    <div class="utvaldbild">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail('produktbild'); ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>

<h2><?php the_title();?></h2>
<p><?php the_field('produktnotis'); ?></p>

<?php if (get_field('nedladdning')) { ?><div class="nedladdning"></div><?php } ?>
</a>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Some code of what you have done would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you could add a custom field to your post custom posttype called numcols or something like that.  normal products would be 1 and super images 2 etc.

then just keep a count of them in your php code and cut off when appropriate.

you could probably modify the query in the lookup page to do this but I'd have to see some code to be of any help. ideally your custom product archive page and the definition of your custom post type.